# Access data deep in a structure using get()

Tags: r, get, apostrophe

I have a `p` structure in R memory and I'm trying to access the `Rate` column of the matrix.

When I type `p$6597858$Sample` in the console, I get ...

```
 p$`6597858`$Sample
        Rate             Available                 X                    Y
[1,]    1.01              1520.93                0.00                  0.0
[2,]    1.02               269.13                0.00                  0.0
[3,]    1.03               153.19                0.00                  0.0
[4,]    1.04               408.80                0.00                  0.0
```

and so on ...

Within my code when I try to

```
get("p$`6597858`$Sample[,1]")
```

I get this returned ...

```
object 'p$`6597858`$Sample[ ,1]' not found
```

Is this an apostrophe problem?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend `get("p[[`6597858`]][["Sample"]][,1]")`; I'd even more strongly recommend avoiding non-standard names and using `get()`, if you can help it ...

Comment: I've been given this complex p structure which has sub structures, one of which is named `6597858`.
> class(p$`6597858`)
[1] "list"

Comment: OK, so you're stuck with the non-standard naming -- but why do you need `get`? what are you trying to do?

Comment: I've been given this complex p structure which has sub structures, one of which is named `6597858`.  This 6597858 value will change over the course of my program hence I need create dynamic variables.

More info ...
> class(p$`6597858`)
[1] "list"

> class (p$`6597858`$Sample)
[1] "matrix"

Comment: I don't think you need `get`, though.  See my example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither the `$` nor the `[[` operator work within `get()` (because `p[[1]]` is not an R object, it's a component of the object `p`).

You could try

```
p <- list(`6597858`=list(Sample=data.frame(Rate=1:3,Available=2:4)))
z <- eval(parse(text="p$`6597858`$Sample[,1]"))
```

but it's probably a bad idea. Is there a reason that

```
z <- p[["6597858"]][["Sample"]][,"Rate"]
```

doesn't do what you want?

You can do this dynamically by using `character` variables to index, still without using `get`: for example

```
needed <- 1234
x <- p[[as.character(needed)]][["Sample"]][,"Rate"]
```

(**edit**: suggested by Hadley Wickham in comments) or

```
x <- p[[c(as.character(needed),"Sample","Rate")]]
```

(*if* the second-lowest-level element is a data frame or list: if it's a matrix, this alternative won't work, you would need `p[[c(as.character(needed),"Sample")]][,"Rate"]` instead)

This is a situation where figuring out the idiom of the language and working with it (rather than struggling against it) will pay off ...

```
library(fortunes)
fortune(106)

If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
   -- Thomas Lumley
      R-help (February 2005)
```

In general,

- extracting elements directly from lists is better (safer, leads to less convoluted code) than using `get()`
- using non-standard names for list elements (i.e. those such as pure numbers that need to be protected by backticks) is unwise
- `[[` is more robust than `$`

Comment: Both of these suggestions worked.
For the 2nd to work, you dropped the leading and trailing apostrophe I notice.  I don't understand  and would never have guessed it originally. 
Thanks for you help Ben! much appreciated. 
I cant vote you up as I don't have the required reputation :)

Comment: backticks are not standard quote characters, they're "protection" characters.  (Using them already means you're venturing into non-standard/tricky areas.)  You can't upvote me, but you can accept the answer (click on the check mark) if you like.

Comment: Two tiny points: in this case you can use quotes and not backticks, and you can slightly shorten the indexing by using recursive indexing: `p[[c(as.character(needed), "Sample", "Rate")]]`